# where is the swagger spec file kept?

Tags: rest, api, swagger

So I am building a Rest API and have used a swagger YAML file to define the API.

I use the swagger editor to view the spec but how do I host / make it available for everyone in our company to browse ?

Does the swagger get bundled with the actual deployed code and then it is accessible ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to host it somewhere. Either simply as a downloadable file, or embedded in an application such as [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/).

Comment: having it as a downloadable file without a visual representation would not be of much use. So having each end user to have their own copy of swagger editor / UI does not sound a good solution. I was hoping that the spec would be cohosted with the API - is that possible ?

Comment: Swagger UI is a web app, so you could host it on your company server. You can also create an endpoint that returns the spec, but then you still have no visual representation.